# Delphi DUnitX tests creation of form twice

Tags: delphi, dunitx

I created a TestCase with DUnitX which automatically generated some code and I'm confused as to how I should structure the test case.

The (automatically generated) code looks like the following:

```
procedure TestTBtnMgmtForm.SetUp;
begin
  FBtnMgmtForm := TBtnMgmtForm.Create;
end;

procedure TestTBtnMgmtForm.TearDown;
begin
  FBtnMgmtForm.Free;
  FBtnMgmtForm := nil;
end;

procedure TestTBtnMgmtForm.TestFormCreate;
var
  Sender: TObject;
begin
  // TODO: Setup method call parameters
  FBtnMgmtForm.FormCreate(Sender);
  // TODO: Validate method results
end;
```

However, `TBtnMgmtForm.Create` will automatically call `.FormCreate`. Is it good practice to separate these two somehow? What is the difference or *should be* the difference between `.Create` and `.FormCreate`?

Comment: FYI There is no mock there. Just the System Under Test and the Test class

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of a form will call the `OnCreate` event handler, if it is assigned. In your case it is assigned, to the function named `FormCreate`.

As a general rule, event handlers are invoked by the framework and should not be called directly. I can't see enough of your code to be sure but my instincts tell me that you should not be calling `FormCreate` at all. It is the job of the framework to do that.

The point of `OnCreate` is that it allows you to inject code into the constructor of the form class without having to override the constructor. You can use the form designer to add the event handler and fill in the code. Personally I regard `OnCreate` as somewhat facile. Once you know how to override constructors it seems more explicit to do that.

You however appear to have a form with a parameterless constructor. That is odd. Usually you would override the virtual constructor declared in `TComponent`. I wonder why you are not doing that.

Comment: This is purely code generated by RAD Studio. You are correct that the parameterless constructor will draw an error. This code was generated to be a test case, so it created a function that tests `FormCreate`. I was confused why it would do that since `FormCreate` is called in every `Setup` as well.

Comment: It doesn't sound as though the IDE is going to be able to write your tests for you. You'd be better off doing it yourself.